# Claudia.Js - Adding Release Tags

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, lambda, claudiajs

Anyone have a clever way to add a Github release tag to a NodeJs flavored AWS Lambda with Claudi.Js, on deployment? We set our Lambdas up initially with Terraform, and then deploy them from Travis using Claudia. I would like to tag them with each release tag.

Technologies:
Terraform
Git
Travis
Claudia
Node 6 (an AWS limitation)
AWS CLI
Bash

Answer (score 0):

Adding release tag to Github is matter of pushing git tags. If you want to do it from CI your CI needs to have rights to push to your repo.
Adding tag is simple, you should be able to follow this tutorial: https://www.barrykooij.com/create-github-releases-via-command-line/